# Formatted headers/footers? Colour Code

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I've found out the way to format header and footer using xlwt (see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/python-excel/3hZP_hK_LSc),

I'm looking for docs or example on how to define the font color for this header and footer? any example.

Answer (score 2):

According to the xlwt [docs](http://open-hea.googlecode.com/hg-history/e3c022eb2a9a895519930b891dc9ac0a8c09020d/docs/html/xlwt.html#xlwt.BIFFRecords.HeaderRecord), you can manage just font, font style and font height. You may have found that there is a special `&K` (e.g. for red `&Kff0000`)  notation for header/footer font color, but it doesn't really work for `xls` (2003) format files.

If you are ok to generate `xlsx` instead - you can choose from [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Here's an example using `openpyxl`:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

ws.header_footer.center_header.font_size = 14
ws.header_footer.center_header.font_name = "Tahoma,Bold"
ws.header_footer.center_header.text = "Hello, World!"
ws.header_footer.center_header.font_color = "FF0000"

wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Here's an example using `xlsxwriter`:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_header('&"Tahoma,Bold"&14&Kff0000Hello, World!')

workbook.close()
```

Hope that helps.